# GC logging when running racket as emacs REPL

Tags: racket

I don't get any GC logging messages when running Racket code in raket-mode in emacs.

Running the following code in DrRacket gives back a log entry while running it in Emacs REPL does not.

```
(define my-logger (make-log-receiver (current-logger) 'debug 'GC))
(collect-garbage)
(sync/timeout 1 my-logger)
```

How can I get the log messages in the Emacs REPL case?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you have a somewhat recent version of racket-mode (e.g. [latest from MELPA](https://melpa.org/#/racket-mode)).
2. Use <kbd>C-c C-l</kbd> a.k.a. [`M-x racket-logger`](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/blob/master/Reference.md#racket-logger) to open a `racket-logger-mode` buffer.
3. If you have any problems or questions, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues).

---

**Update**: The above instructions don't really answer why your own program isn't getting a log event. This is a really interesting bug -- thanks! More conversation on [the issue thread](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/325). When I figure it out, I'll try to come back here and update this answer again with something hopefully interesting and educational about Racket logging.

---

**Update**: This turned out to be a "what was I thinking?" bug in racket-mode. I was creating a new logger:

```
(define global-logger (make-logger))
  (current-logger global-logger)
```

rather than just using the existing one:

```
(define global-logger (current-logger))
```

The existing logger is special, as [the Racket documentation for loggers](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/logging.html) explains:

> On start-up, Racket creates an initial logger that is used to record events from the core run-time system. For example, an `'debug` event is reported for each garbage collection (see [Garbage Collection](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/eval-model.html#%28part._gc-model%29)).

I've pushed a commit to a topic branch and when I get all-green from CI I'll merge to master; it should be available via MELPA soon after.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have done that and the result is exactly the same, no log message from GC. I'm using racket-mode version 20180824.1410, racket 6.9

Comment: I saw your [issue](https://github.com/greghendershott/racket-mode/issues/325) -- thanks! This seems unique to the GC logger, so possibly a bug in racket-mode, so I'll continue the conversation there.